# Does ActivateDeviceEx start a driver?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mobile, pinvoke

I am developing a Windows Mobile 6.1 application and I am running into a problem where when the mobile device is docked it loads the USB driver for an Ethernet connection and unloads it when it is undocked.  After a few times the driver doesn't appear to load, so my solution was to load it manually from the application itself.

Below is my P/Invoke declaration and usage:

```
[DllImport("Coredll.dll")]
extern static IntPtr ActivateDeviceEx(string device, IntPtr regEnts, 
    UInt32 cRegEnts, IntPtr devKey);

IntPtr handle = ActivateDeviceEx(
    "Drivers\\USB\\ClientDrivers\\ADMTEK_LANUSB_Driver",
    IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

I get a valid handle, but my question is, what exactly happens when you activate the device driver? My problem is that the driver is not automatically getting a LAN connection, is what I am doing enough to force it to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a stream driver with `ActivateDeviceExe` as if the driver would reside at the `HKLM\Drivers\BuiltIn` subkey. These drivers are loaded by the driver loader of device.exe.

Other drivers like NDIS Minport drivers or USB client drivers are loaded by the corresponding subsystem. They need to be loaded in the corresponding context. Calling `ActivateDeviceEx` doesn't neither initiate the loading of the subsystem nor preparing the context to put these kind of drivers into an operation state. Therefore you can't use `ActivdateDeviceExe` to load these drivers.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this was bugging me for years! :)